# Show php response text with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, select

I have a function onChange my select that show some text from php. I'm using ajax to do this request without reload the whole page. 
The problem for me is I have many divs with one class, and I want to show the result from ajax matching with the select i've changed:

```
    <div class="x">
      <select class="mySelect">
        <option>1</option>  
        <option>2</option>
      </select>   
      <div class="showHere">php text requested with ajax</div>
    </div>

<div class="x">
      <select class="mySelect">
        <option>1</option>  
        <option>2</option>
      </select>   
      <div class="showHere">php text requested with ajax</div>
    </div>

<div class="x">
      <select class="mySelect">
        <option>1</option>  
        <option>2</option>
      </select>   
      <div class="showHere">php text requested with ajax</div>
    </div>
```

The line in ajax:

```
 document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

I want to show the response in the div class "showHere" but in the RIGHT div, in the other words in the div matching with my select i've changed, got it? I don't know if it's possible...

Comment: you described your own problem, all your elements are the same. if you need to target elements specifically, you need to give them a way to specify them. html Ids would work well for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you could use the sender of the event and shorten the whole thing. Fill the result of the AJAX call in the following element (this requires that the div is always directly after the select).

With this code you get the element that triggered the event (the event.srcElement is a fallback in case of the user working with ie which does not interpret event.target correctly):

```
var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
```

This part selects the next element after your select:

```
var nextDiv = target.nextSibling;
```

Now add your response:

```
nextDiv.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need something to distinguish the divs. Could give them an ID, and pass this to the AJAX function as parameter in your event.

```
div class="x">
      <select class="mySelect">
        <option>1</option>  
        <option>2</option>
      </select>   
      <div class="showHere" id="first">php text requested with ajax</div>
    </div>

<div class="x">
      <select class="mySelect">
        <option>1</option>  
        <option>2</option>
      </select>   
      <div class="showHere" id="second">php text requested with ajax</div>
    </div>

<div class="x">
      <select class="mySelect">
        <option>1</option>  
        <option>2</option>
      </select>   
      <div class="showHere" id="third">php text requested with ajax</div>
    </div>


In your script:

function ajaxCall(id_of_target_div) {
    ...
    document.getElementById(id_of_target_div).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText ;
}
```